# What will happen use run() instead of start() of a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Fallowing thread class is working fine. I can understand its process. Then I changed

**mc.srart()** into **mc.run()** but nothing changed and there was no any errors.

Can someone please explain this to me ? can we always use **run()** instead of **start()** ?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Myclass mc = new Myclass();
        mc.start();
    }
}

class Myclass extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "--");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `t.start()` is the method that the library provides for your code to call in order to start a new thread.  `run()` is the method that your code provides for the library to call _in_ the new thread.  The `run()` method is the method that defines what the thread will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `run` directly on a `Thread` object defeats the point of having the `Thread` in the first place.

If you call `run`, then `run` will execute in the current `Thread`, as a normal method.  You must call [the `start`method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) on the `Thread` to have `run` execute in a different `Thread`.

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.